# Hard disk slowly losing space despite not downloading anything

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I am really worried -

The last few days I keep deleting things, then notice the space dwindling. Today, I kept a close eye. An hour ago, I made 12.5 GB free space on laptop. Checked just now and only 10 GB remaining. I am not downloading anything. Why is my space disappearing?!?!

Comment: https://windirstat.net/

Answer (score 1):

Use WinDirStat to visualise the disk and find what's growing: https://windirstat.net/